# python3 looping a list with 1 variable at a time

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

still learning python, so I apologize if this question is sloppy.

I am familiar with loops, and looping through a file. However, I have not found the correct referance to looping a file, storing the variable and calling that variable into another function, and maintain the increment.

Using pyautogui and pywinauto.

Written form:

```
get names.txt file with list of 20 or so names (the list changes so keeping track of line count seems reasonable) 
Split the text of the file for parsing.
```

in example:

setup of name.txt file.

```
Mark
James
Sam
Steve
```

.

```
def do(name):
# open and read file
fname = 'names.txt'
for name in (open(fname, "r")).readlines():
    print("Found: " + name)
    more(name)
```

Output:
['Mark', 'James', 'Sam', 'Steve]

```
def more(name):
    pyautogui.moveT0(600,511)
    pyautogui.click()
    pyautogui.typewrite(a[0])
    pyautogui.moveTo(699,412)
    pyautogui.press("enter")
    confirm(name)

def confirm(name)
    pic = pyscreenshot.grab(bbox=(8,11,211,728))
    f = "images/active"
    g = "images/go"
    pic.save(f + a + ".png")
    pic.save(g + ".png")
    b = Image.open("images/go.png"
    text = image_to_search(b, lang='eng')
    if text == name:
        print("Success")
    else:
        print("Mismatch")
```

This is the part where the function will end and start back at the top of the program increment our digit and applying the next name for searching. The confirm program (already completed) takes an image of the search field and passes the text. If the name is equal to the name in the list (a[0]) then we move onto the next name.

Bringing up another question of how to "call a variable from a function"?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. As it is right now you are unlikely to get much help from the community. It is not clear what your question is (please read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and the code you've provided contains a lot that is irrelevant (please provide an MCVE  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I was afraid of that. This is the best way I could ask this question. 

Basically the end of the program runs through 15 more steps in pyautogui then ends. 

I need to take a vaule from a list, and process the line, then go back for the next line and repeat until the file has been used. The program is designed to check users that are on another system. 

We pull the list then validate who still exists. The software we are writing to does not have an api, so we are building a method to input a name, observe and record the results and continue to the next name.

Comment: @imhotep: Suggest you to put all the information you gave in comment to put in question itself

Comment: How does it matter if you read all the names and then process them 1 by 1 or read a name process it, then go to the next name? In either case it is achievable without keeping track of stuff like line number.

Comment: Also if I understand correctly are yu reading names from a file and then inputting them into the gui of a program and every time you input a name you are modifying the co-ordinates a little bit ?

Comment: @Sirini You are correct, I am placing the data into the GUI, Currently I am not changing the coordinates. Yes I am trying to process the names 1 by 1, I was hoping to not need to worry about line counts. I just havent figured out the best approach to getting to the next name without a  i++ as I am used to from Pick Basic and C++.

Comment: ok, great, and what appears to be the problem? you pretty much do it in your `def more` fn. You don;t really need `enumerate` but it would work. Except for the fact that your return statement is indented one level up (which is probably a typo). But if that was indeed the case I suggest you look into `yield` to preserve loop iteration depth when calling a fn repeatedly

Comment: I am only printing out the first 2 results in a

Comment: @Sirini The second issue is the variable in more() are not being called.

Comment: you are using terms like *call* , *module* and *function* not in the right context. *The confirm program (already completed) takes an image of the search field and passes the text* . What does this even mean? is `confirm` a function? They why do you call it a *program* ? What does `a` or any of the actions of `confirm` have anything to do with the error you are facing?

Comment: @Srini apologies for my syntax being a bit off, I have been working with to many languages.

lets forget confirm it is using pytesseract. it is passing 'a' as an argument witch is established in the do(): << This is a method right? if so, than the do method. 

to try to simplify, I want to do the following:

    open text file
    get name
    insert name into search field
    press enter
    Confirm(a)
    Get the next name
    insert into search field

Answer (score 0):

First off, **your code is rife with indentation, syntactical and logcial errors, you have to fix those before you apply the below**

```
def file_stuff(a, fname):
    for name in (open(fname, "r")).readlines():
        print ("Found: " + name)
        gui_stuff(name)

def gui_stuff(name):
    pyautogui.moveT0(600,511)
    pyautogui.click()
    pyautogui.typewrite(name) # ATTENTION, please confirm if this is how the typewriter fn works. you are only printing the first char
    pyautogui.moveTo(699,412)
    pyautogui.press("enter")
    confirm(name)
```

Please fix the if-else indentation in your confirm function, and other dangling indentation references in your code

Comment: ! Wow thank you! I certainly have a TON of learning to do. This seems to work pretty well!